# Criar bat para mover arquivos retornados pelo findstr

Tags: batch, cmd, prompt

Boa tarde a todos!

Tenho me deparado com um problema diário onde, possuo vários .xml para abrir e verificar se estes possuem as tags:

```
< desc_produto >Riscos< /desc_Produto >"
```

ou

```
< tp_mov>P01< /tp_mov>
```

Para fazer isso, estava realizando este procedimento manualmente, mas decidi fazer um .bat que possa me facilitar a vida.
Encontrei o comando findstr que realiza esse procedimento (Windows 7).
Até o momento só estou executando no prompt o seguinte comando:

```
findstr /i /s "< desc_produto>Riscos< /desc_Produto>" *. *
```

Porém, gostaria melhorar o .bat, onde, ao executá-lo, o  sistema verificará no conteúdo de todos os .xml da pasta para encontrar os arquivos que possuem essa tag texto. E ao encontrar esses arquivos, que crie uma pasta Riscos e mova-os para dentro dela.

Alguém poderia por favor me ajudar com essa necessidade?

Comment: A resposta te ajudou a resolver o problema? É possível aceitá-la ou precisa de alguma informação complementar?

Comment: Opa! Me ajudou muito, era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Só que eu não sei como faço pra aceitá-la e encerrar a pergunta! Sou novo no stackoverflow

Comment: Você pode dar 1 ponto para a resposta, na seta para cima e mais abaixo da seta, tem um sinal de "certo", onde você aceita a resposta.

Comment: @Bueno Boa tarde, achei meio fora do normal as suas tags xml estarem com espaços no enunciado, elas são assim mesmos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize `for` para percorrer o resultado da sua busca com `findstr`.

Crie um batch `findtags.bat` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
@echo off
rem Garante que as variáveis de ambiente tenham escopo local
    setlocal
rem Cria diretório não retornando erro se já existe
    if not exist Riscos\. md Riscos
rem Busca em subdiretórios retornando nome dos arquivos encontrados
    for /f %%a in ('findstr /I /S /M "< desc_produto>Riscos< /desc_Produto>" *.*') do (
        echo Movendo %%a
        move %%a Riscos\
    )
    endlocal
```

Comment: Muuuuuito obrigado! Me ajudou demais, era exatamente isso que eu estava precisando!

Agora, seguindo a mesma lógica, é possível incluir dois itens em uma verificação? exemplo:

Se no mesmo xml possuir as tags < desc_produto>Riscos< /desc_produto> e também possuir a tag < tp_mov>P01< /tp_mov>, então mova pra pasta XXXX

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Sim, você utilizar regex no findstr com /R para esta busca. Ou você pode fazer a segunda busca no arquivo retornado como: findstr "blabla" %%a

Answer (score 0):

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Resposta considerando questionamento no comentário para filtragens de pasta de destino onde haja ocorrências de múltiplas strings ou não, usando o **`findstr`**....

É possível usar **`findstr`** e agir conforme responder a saída aos **`operadores`**:

> • Observações sobre os operadores & | && e || e seus empregos conforme o **comportamento** dos seus **comandos**:

---

```
execute & execute & execute 
execute | recebe _saída_do_comando_anterior 
execute | recebe _saída_do_comando_anterior & execute
executou_sem_erro && então_execute_também 
executou_com_erro || execute_também_porque_deu_erro 
executou_com_erro || executou_com_erro || executou_com_erro 
executou_sem_erro && executou_sem_erro && executou_sem_erro 
executou_sem_erro && então_execute || execute_esse_no_primeiro_deu_erro
```

---

Daí é só seguir a lógica:

```
acho o 1º ? sim e achou também o 2º ? sim (então) faz X ! (string && string && faz X)  
acho o 1º ? sim e achou também o 2º ? não (então) faz Y ! (string && string || faz Y)  
acho o 1º ? não e achou também o 2º ? não (então) faz Z ! (string || string || faz Z)  

Para:: 

achou !_str_1! ? sim e achou também a !_str_2! ? sim (então) mover p\ Risco !
achou !_str_1! ? sim e achou também a !_str_2! ? não (então) mover p\ Arisco !
achou !_str_1! ? não e achou também a !_str_2! ? não (então) Não mover !
```

---

> Exemplo no código:

---

```
type "%~1"|!_sys!findstr /i "!_str_1:^=!" >nul) && (!_sys!findstr /i "!_str_2:^=!" "%~1"
```

---

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion & mode 102,5 & title <nul 

title Q200198 & set "_sys=%__appdir__%" & for /f %%c in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul')do set "_cr=%%c"
for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (0)do rem"')do set "_bs=%%a" & for %%l in (1 1 90)do set "_spc=!_spc! "

2>nul >nul (mkdir .\Riscos & mkdir .\Arisco) & set "_dir_1=Arisco" & set "_dir_2=Riscos" & echo/ & echo/ 
set "_str_1=\^<\ tp_mov\^>P01\^<\ \/tp_mov\^>" && set "_str_2=\^<\ desc_produto\^>Riscos\^<\ \/desc_produto\^>"

for /f %%f in ('!_sys!where /r "%cd%" "*.xml" ^|findstr /vi "!_dir_1! !_dir_2!"')do call :^) "%%~f" "%cd%\!_dir_1!" "%cd%\!_dir_2!"
echo/!_cr!&& goto :^?

:^)
set "_dest=.." && set _msg=<nul & 2>nul ((
(type "%~1"|!_sys!findstr /i "!_str_1:^=!" >nul) && (!_sys!findstr /i "!_str_2:^=!" "%~1"  >nul) && (
move /y "%~1" "%~2" >nul & set "_dest=Riscos")))||((type "%~1"|!_sys!findstr /i "!_str_2:^=!" >nul) && (
move /y "%~1" "%~3" >nul & set "_dest=Arisco")) >nul 
echo/!_cr! & if "!_dest!" == ".." (set "_msg= Arquivo Analisado "%~nx1" -^> Tags nao encontradas !_spc!"
     ) else (set "_msg=  Arquivo Analisado: "%~nx1" -^> Movido para a pasta !_dest! !_cr!")
      <nul set /p"^=!_bs!!_cr!!_msg:~0,100!!_cr!" & ping -n 2 -4 127.0 >nul & call :^] "!_msg:~0,100!"
      exit /b 

:^]
for /f %%h in ('cmd /u/c set /p "^=%_msg:"= %"^<nul^|find /v /c "^|"')do (
     for /l %%H in (1 1 !_i!)do <nul set /p"^=!_bs!") && exit /b 

:^?
```

---

Comment: @Bueno Depois coma mais tempo, ainda vou por os respectivos comentário nos códigos, qualquer dúvida ou "ajuste" necessário, comente... obrigado...gostei de sua pergunta...

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem e queria fazer a mesma coisa enviar do o aquivo com a Palacra "banana" para outro diretorio.

Comment: Esta resposta ficaria melhor como `Comentário`.